# Pandas to_dict list-like output

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have  a dataframe like this,

```
Roll No     date     status     Name
1           1/1/2020  on         A
2           1/1/2020  on         A
3           1/1/2020  on         B
```

I am trying to create a dictionary where key will be the names and value will be list of roll numbers,
I am unable to handle the duplicate name,

my expected output is,

```
{
    "A" :[1,2],
    "B" :[3]
}
```

I can get my output by iterating the dataframe, I am looking for a `pandorable` way, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with convert to lists in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and then [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby('Name')['Roll No'].agg(list).to_dict()
```